# ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type (chrome-extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE  
ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a 
ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').
```

Error log.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/scripts/sw.js").then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
});
```

I tried to use a service worker in chrome-extension, but this error occurred. I couldn't find a solution, so I asked. Thank you very much.

Comment: See the [official demo extension](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6ddb7d6a7dcfa4364aa4c4c6afb82fdb16b00645/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/service_worker/background/). Also maybe js MIME type is broken in your OS, see https://crbug.com/762483

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I solved the problem, but I won't be able to deploy any other Windows users.

Comment: Could you post your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MIME type for the service-worker file (/scripts/sw.js) to **"application/javascript"**

For instance my files are hosted on ASW's S3, so I upload them as follows:

```
aws s3 cp service-worker.js  s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/service-worker.js --acl public-read
```

Adn the bucket will take care of the rest. Not sure where your file is hosted, but you need to configure it so that it returns the correct type for that file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Your need to specify the mime/content type in your server config. On nginx e.g.

```
types {
    text/html                               html htm shtml;
    text/css                                css;
    text/xml                                xml rss;
    image/gif                               gif;
    image/jpeg                              jpeg jpg;
    application/x-javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                    atom;}
```

this goes in the /etc/nginx/mime.types

Answer (score -1):

ServiceWorker supported MIME type are 'text/javascript', application/javascript and application/x-javascript.
got to ur server file and set

```
    response.writeHead(201, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

in the host manager, Cpanel
go to root/public_html/
open .htaccess
and add

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # DEFAULTS
    DefaultLanguage en
    AddLanguage en-US .html .css .js
    AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss .atom

    # JAVASCRIPT
    AddType application/javascript js jsonp
    AddType application/json json

    # FONTS
    AddType font/opentype otf
    AddType application/font-woff woff
    AddType application/x-font-woff woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf
    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz

    # AUDIO
    AddType audio/mp4 m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg oga ogg

    # VIDEO
    AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg ogv
    AddType video/webm webm
    AddType video/x-flv flv

    # OTHERS
    AddType application/octet-stream safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall xpi
    AddType application/xml atom rdf rss xml
    AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats .docx .pptx .xlsx .xltx . xltm .dotx .potx .ppsx
    AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt vtt
    AddType text/x-component htc
    AddType text/x-vcard vcf
    AddType image/webp webp
    AddType image/x-icon ico

</IfModule>
```